Cleaning up background tasks in a classes Dispose() without risking deadlock
Sometimes in C# .NET Framework 4.8 I'll have a class that does some async stuff in the background, usually networking or other IO stuff. I want it to stop and clean-up if Dispose() is called, but it seems this pattern can result in deadlock if somehow Dispose() got called from the background task itself (I suspect a similar flaw would be possible with plain threads as well).

A TaskCompletionSource.SetResult etc. in some form can cause some external await to continue on the thread that was running the background task which then calls dispose.
Sometimes the background task invoked a callback/event and somehow that ultimately ended up calling Dispose before returning.

Is there a standard pattern for safely running background operations such as network clients?

Should I avoid Dispose() functions waiting for background stuff to finish and use some other method to ensure everything stopped before returning from main?
Is it always the fault of the code calling Dispose() for letting it happen from a "callback" (with traditional threads it seems many libraries will say this, but the await foo potential context switch makes threads much harder to control)?
Should I avoid background tasks invoking callbacks on their own thread (events/Action/Func, Subject<T>.OnNext(), TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(), etc.)?

Very simplified example that would break, normally the BackgroundTask would be something like a WebSocket or other network service that hangs around until the application is closed.
public sealed class BackgroundTask : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new();
    private readonly Task _task;
    // Probably some sort of message queue
    private TaskCompletionSource? _thingToDoTcs;
    public BackgroundTask()
    {
        _task = TaskMainAsync(_cts.Token);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        _task.Wait();
    }
    public Task DoSomethingOnTask()
    {
        _thingToDoTcs = new();
        return _thingToDoTcs.Task;
    }
    private async Task TaskMainAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            if (_thingToDoTcs != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Doing a thing...");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                _thingToDoTcs.SetResult();
            }
            // Doing other stuff as well, e.g. a Socket read loop
        }
    }

    static async Task AsyncMain()
    {
        using var background = new BackgroundTask();
        var task = background.DoSomethingOnTask();
        Console.WriteLine("Doing other stuff...");
        await task; // May continue on a different thread to the caller
        Console.WriteLine("Done everything, time to shut down.");
        // Can deadlock because `await task` ends up being the thread running TaskMainAsync
        // and then Dispose() calls .Wait() on it.
        // `using` blocks make implicit on return, exception, etc. so can't fully control call site
        background.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncMain().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Exit main");
    }
}


There some issues in this code. For starters, Main can be async Task Main(). Second BackgroundTask isn't a task at all - tasks already run in the "background". This is more of a background job, something already supported through the IHostedService interface and a basic BackgroundService implementation. Check the timed background tasks example. This isn't ASP.NET Core specific.

@PanagiotisKanavos This was based on some older code, I don't think async Main exists in framework? I guess I can see if the libraries are available for .NET 4.8  but it means none of the surrounding application uses the new hosted services or DI stuff. You are right on the naming was poor, I just meant "task" in the generic sense of "some work" like a network client/server.

They're available and I've used them to host ETL pipelines using DataFlow blocks, before moving to .NET Core entirely. The basic Microsoft.Extensions.* packages target .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.2 as well. How is  DoSomethingOnTask though? Running a job in the background is one thing. Trying to coordinate multiple jobs/services is trickier

You can use IAsyncDisposable instead, to do an awaitable dispose. Note the use of await using rather than a normal using.
In .NET Framework you need the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces package.
public sealed class BackgroundTask : IAsyncDisposable
{
......
    public ValueTask Dispose()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        await _task;
    }
......
    static async Task AsyncMain()
    {
        await using var background = new BackgroundTask();
        var task = background.DoSomethingOnTask();
        Console.WriteLine("Doing other stuff...");
        await task; // May continue on a different thread to the caller
        Console.WriteLine("Done everything, time to shut down.");
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
    }


Isn't that a .NET Core thing, this is Framework 4.8?

@FireLancer you can use .NET Core features in .NET Framework as well by adding the proper packages, including the generic host, DI and IHostedService/BackgroundService classes that do what you want. IAsyncDisposable is available in Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces (I think)

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks good point.
